# Flash Descriptor write-protection defaults

Tags: hardware, known-vulnerabilities, backdoor, firmware

According to Intel in [this article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025619/software.html), to exploit Intel SA 00086 an attacker needs physical access if Flash Descriptor write protections are enabled.

I assembled my computer myself, and it doesn't look like ASUS is going to release patches for single motherboards, especially not for older ones like mine, so I'd like to know if write-protection is enabled by default on my motherboard.

I have a Z77 mounting an i7-3770. Am I vulnerable to remote exploits?